# Getting a Youtube Video URL to show in the RSS description field?

Tags: rss, youtube, yahoo-pipes

Here's my problem. I need to take a standard youtube feed output, like this:

> F is for Fireflies by Kathy jo Wargin Book Trailer
>
> F is for Fireflies is written by award winning prolific children's
>   author, Kathy-jo Wargin. This
>   beautifully illustrated book explores
>   God's warmest, wonder filled season
>   from A to Z, by delighting young
>   readers with beaches and sandcastles,
>   picnics and lemonade, and all of the
>   blessings that God's summer brings.
>   Learn more about this book here,
>   http://bit.ly/fyLd2L and its author
>   here, http://bit.ly/gPQcSq  Christian,
>   Childrens

And render it like this:

> F is for Fireflies by Kathy jo Wargin Book Trailer
>
> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vp6kDK2eYLU&feature=youtube_gdata
>
> F is for Fireflies is written by award winning prolific children's
>   author, Kathy-jo Wargin. This
>   beautifully illustrated book explores
>   God's warmest, wonder filled season
>   from A to Z, by delighting young
>   readers with beaches and sandcastles,
>   picnics and lemonade, and all of the
>   blessings that God's summer brings.
>   Learn more about this book here,
>   http://bit.ly/fyLd2L and its author
>   here, http://bit.ly/gPQcSq  Christian,
>   Childrens

**I've been trying to accomplish this in Yahoo! Pipes, but I can't figure out how to get  a plain-text URL into the description field *with* the normal YT Description. Any suggestions?**

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to use a Loop module with a StringBuilder module. Then you can use item.link and item.description to build up your string and save it back into the description field.

Here is a pipe that takes a Youtube search term and returns an RSS feed with the link added to the beginning of the description:

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=7e18b28120534e7b116b482893b2fdfd